# Primefaces 6 & Content Flow Error

Tags: primefaces, xhtml

I get **java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter url is null.**

xhtml file:

```html
<p:dataTable var="vehicleTransactionList" value="#{viewCompanyManagedBean.vehicleTransactionList}">
<p:column headerText="#{messages.saptrn}">
<h:outputText value="#{vehicleTransactionList.vehicleTransactionId}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="#{messages.scalepics}"> 
<p:contentFlow value="#{viewCompanyManagedBean.vehicleTransactionList}" var="newimage">
<p:graphicImage value="#{newimage.imageLocations}" styleClass="content" />
<div class="caption">#{newimage.imageLocations}</div>
</p:contentFlow>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The error is on the 2nd column **#{newimage.imageLocations}**

Managed Bean:

```js
package com.company.beans;

import com.company.entities.Company;

import com.company.entities.Scale;
import com.company.entities.ScaleMeasurement;
import com.company.entities.VehicleTransaction;
import com.company.services.db.ScaleMeasurementService;
import com.company.services.db.ScaleService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

import sunw.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewCompanyManagedBean implements Serializable {
 static Logger webRecySys = null;
    static {
     webRecySys = Logger.getLogger("com.company.webRecySys");     
    }
 
 public ViewCompanyManagedBean() {
  
 }
 @PostConstruct
 public void populateCompanyData() { 
  prepareData(new Date());
  
        images = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            images.add("file_" + i + ".jpg");
        }
 }
 @PostConstruct
 public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent event) throws UnknownHostException {
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  String date = format.format(event.getObject());
  try {
   Date selectedDate = format.parse(date);
   prepareData(selectedDate);       
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  facesContext.addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Date Selected",format.format(event.getObject())));
 }
 
 private void prepareData(Date forData) {
  ScaleService ss = new ScaleService();
  ScaleMeasurementService sms = new ScaleMeasurementService();
  Scale right = ss.find(getRightScale());
  Scale left = ss.find(getLeftScale());
  this.measurements = sms.getMeasurementForScale(right,forData);
  this.measurements.addAll(sms.getMeasurementForScale(left,forData));
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
  this.fileName = "Shredder_Measurements_"+  sdf.format(forData);
  for ( ScaleMeasurement s : measurements ) {
   if ( s.getScale().getScaleId().equalsIgnoreCase(rightScale) ) { 
    this.rightScaleMeasurementSum += s.getMeasurement();
   }
   if ( s.getScale().getScaleId().equalsIgnoreCase(leftScale) ) { 
    this.leftScaleMeasurementSum += s.getMeasurement();
   }
  }
  vehicleTransactionList = getVehicleTransactionList( sdf.format(forData) , (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest() );
 }
 
 
 private ArrayList<VehicleTransaction> getVehicleTransactionList(String fileDateFormat,HttpServletRequest request) {
  
  ResourceBundle resourceb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.company.messages.image");
  String imgRootPath = resourceb.getString("imagerootpath");
  
  ArrayList<VehicleTransaction> images = new ArrayList<VehicleTransaction>();
  String name = request.getLocalName();
  if ( name != null ) {
   if ( name.startsWith("0") ) {
    name = "localhost";
   }
  }
  else {
   name = "localhost";
  }

  Scale scale = new ScaleService().find("01");
  Company c = new ScaleService().getCompanyFromScale(scale);
  String companyName = c.getCompanyName().trim().replace(" ", "_");  
  String URL = "http://"+name+":"+request.getLocalPort()+imgRootPath+"/"+companyName+"/"+fileDateFormat+"/";
  
  ArrayList<String> picUrls = new ArrayList<String>();  
  Document doc;
  try {
   doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
    for (Element file : doc.select("a")) {
     String urlPathToFile =  file.attr("href");
     String fileName = file.text();
     if ( urlPathToFile.endsWith(".jpg") && fileName.endsWith(".jpg") ) {
      String picUrl =  "http://"+name+":"+request.getLocalPort()+imgRootPath+"/"+companyName+"/"+fileDateFormat+"/"+fileName;
      
      picUrls.add(picUrl);      
     }
       }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   webRecySys.logp(Level.WARNING,  this.getClass().getCanonicalName() , "getAllImagesList", "Cannot get list of Images: "+e.getMessage() );
  } 
  ArrayList<String> vehicleTransactionIdList = getVehicleTransactionIds(picUrls);
  
  for ( String  vehicleTransactionId : vehicleTransactionIdList) {
   ArrayList<String> imagesForTransaction = getVehicleTransaction(vehicleTransactionId,picUrls);
   VehicleTransaction s = new VehicleTransaction(imagesForTransaction, vehicleTransactionId);
   images.add(s);
  }
  
  return images;
 }
 private ArrayList<String> getVehicleTransaction(String vehicleTransactionId,ArrayList<String> picUrls) {
  ArrayList<String> imagesForTransaction = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (String url : picUrls) { 
   if ( url.contains(vehicleTransactionId)) {
    imagesForTransaction.add(url);
   }
  }
  return imagesForTransaction;
 }
 
 private ArrayList<String> getVehicleTransactionIds(ArrayList<String> picUrls) {
  ArrayList<String> vehicleTransactionIds = new ArrayList<String>();
  for ( String pic : picUrls ) {
   String vehicleTransactionId = pic.substring(pic.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
   vehicleTransactionId = vehicleTransactionId.substring(0,vehicleTransactionId.indexOf("_"));
   if ( !existsInArl(vehicleTransactionId,vehicleTransactionIds) ) {
    vehicleTransactionIds.add(vehicleTransactionId);
   }
  }
  return vehicleTransactionIds;
 }
 private boolean existsInArl (String s , ArrayList<String> arl) {
  boolean exists = false;
  for ( String c : arl ) {
   if ( c.equalsIgnoreCase(s) ) {
    exists = true;
   }
  }
  return exists;
 }
 
 public Date getDate() {
  return date;
 }

 public void setDate(Date date) {
  this.date = date;
 }

 public List<ScaleMeasurement> getMeasurements() {
  return measurements;
 }
 public void setMeasurements(List<ScaleMeasurement> measurements) {
  this.measurements = measurements;
 }
 public String getFileName() {
  return fileName;
 }
 public void setFileName(String fileName) {
  this.fileName = fileName;
 }
 public List<String> getImages() {
  return images;
 }
 public void setImages(List<String> images) {
  this.images = images;
 } 
 public String getRightScale() {
  return rightScale;
 }
 public void setRightScale(String rightScale) {
  this.rightScale = rightScale;
 }
 public String getLeftScale() {
  return leftScale;
 }
 public void setLeftScale(String leftScale) {
  this.leftScale = leftScale;
 }
 public int getRightScaleMeasurementSum() {
  return rightScaleMeasurementSum;
 }
 public void setRightScaleMeasurementSum(int rightScaleMeasurementSum) {
  this.rightScaleMeasurementSum = rightScaleMeasurementSum;
 }
 public int getLeftScaleMeasurementSum() {
  return leftScaleMeasurementSum;
 }
 public void setLeftScaleMeasurementSum(int leftScaleMeasurementSum) {
  this.leftScaleMeasurementSum = leftScaleMeasurementSum;
 }
 public ArrayList<VehicleTransaction> getVehicleTransactionList() {
  return vehicleTransactionList;
 }
 public void setVehicleTransactionList(
   ArrayList<VehicleTransaction> vehicleTransactionList) {
  this.vehicleTransactionList = vehicleTransactionList;
 }

 // Used for Calendar
 private Date date;
 // Used for Shredder Measurements 
 private List<ScaleMeasurement> measurements = new ArrayList<ScaleMeasurement>();
 private String fileName;
 private String rightScale = "02";
 private String leftScale = "03";
 private int rightScaleMeasurementSum;
 private int leftScaleMeasurementSum;
 
 // Used for Pictures 
    private List<String> images;
    private ArrayList<VehicleTransaction> vehicleTransactionList = new ArrayList<VehicleTransaction>();
    

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 7449888248791054139L;
}
```

VehicleTransaction Pojo:

```js
package com.company.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VehicleTransaction {
 public VehicleTransaction() {
  
 }
 public VehicleTransaction(ArrayList<String> imageLocations, String vehicleTransactionId) {
  super();
  this.imageLocations = imageLocations;
  this.vehicleTransactionId = vehicleTransactionId;
 }
 public ArrayList<String> getImageLocations() {
  return imageLocations;
 }
 public void setImageLocations(ArrayList<String> imageLocations) {
  this.imageLocations = imageLocations;
 }
 public String getVehicleTransactionId() {
  return vehicleTransactionId;
 }
 public void setVehicleTransactionId(String vehicleTransactionId) {
  this.vehicleTransactionId = vehicleTransactionId;
 }
 private ArrayList<String> imageLocations;
 private String vehicleTransactionId;
}
```

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

resolved - the right xhtml code is:

```html
<p:column headerText="#{messages.scalepics}"> 
<p:contentFlow value="#{vehicleTransactionList.imageLocations}" var="images">
<p:graphicImage value="#{images}" styleClass="content" />
<div class="caption">#{images}</div>
</p:contentFlow>
</p:column>
```

Whereas the wrong code was:

```html
<p:contentFlow value="#{viewCompanyManagedBean.vehicleTransactionList}" var="newimage">
<p:graphicImage value="#{newimage.imageLocations}" styleClass="content" />
<div class="caption">#{newimage.imageLocations}</div>
```

Comment: Care to add some comment to what the difference is? So others do not have to do a manual 'diff'

Comment: <p:contentFlow value="#{viewCompanyManagedBean.vehicleTransactionList}" var="newimage">
<p:graphicImage value="#{newimage.imageLocations}" styleClass="content" />
<div class="caption">#{newimage.imageLocations}</div>